# Slow startup every other boot, and can't access internal HDDs

Tags: boot, hard-drive, startup

I'm running 15.04 on a 250GB Samsung SSD. I have two HDD's (1 TB and 2 TB). I experience problems every other boot.

Initially the system will boot lightning fast and my drives are immediately accessible. However, after a restart, the system takes 5+ minutes to start up and I can't mount the drives. On the next reboot, everything is great again.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.
```

Comment: Perform these commands and let us know what's going on: `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze plot > test.svg`

Comment: systemd-analyze critical-chain returns "Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later."

Comment: Is there a file `/run/nologin`?

Comment: No. However, on a hunch, I checked one of the disks during a successful boot, and there were bad sectors. I disconnected the drive. And have successfully rebooted, surprisingly quickly, a few times in a row. Looks like it's time for a new one. Thanks for your willingness to help though. It is appreciated.